# Perl read line by line

Tags: perl

I have a simple Perl script to read a file line by line. Code is below. I want to display two lines and break the loop. But it doesn't work. Where is the bug?

```
$file='SnPmaster.txt';
open(INFO, $file) or die("Could not open  file.");

$count = 0; 
foreach $line (<INFO>)  {   
    print $line;    
    if ($++counter == 2){
      last;
    }
}
close(INFO);
```

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` would solve all your problems.

Comment: parsed as `($+ + 'counter') == 2`

Comment: Please don't use old style FILEHANDLES anymore.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

If you had `use strict` turned on, you would have found out that `$++foo` doesn't make any sense.

Here's how to do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'SnPmaster.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {   
    print $line;    
    last if $. == 2;
}

close $info;
```

This takes advantage of the special variable `$.` which keeps track of the line number in the current file. (See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html))

If you want to use a counter instead, use

```
my $count = 0;
while( my $line = <$info>)  {   
    print $line;    
    last if ++$count == 2;
}
```

Comment: +1 but `for my $line (<$filehandle>)` reads the whole file into a temporary list, which can waste memory. `while(my $line = <$filehandle>)` works just as well (and Perl correctly interprets it to mean `while(defined(my $line = <$filehandle>))` so blank lines don't muck it up) without reading the whole file unnecessarily.

Comment: May be try to replace `$.` by some value related to the file `$info->input_line_number()` : Perl best practices - do not use magic punctuation.

Answer (score 12):

With these types of complex programs, it's better to let Perl generate the Perl code for you:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -pe'exit if $.>2'
```

Which will gladly tell you the answer,

```
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    exit if $. > 2;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply run it as such from the command line,

```
$ perl -pe'exit if$.>2' file.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to use `++$counter`, *not* `$++counter`, hence the reason it isn't working..

Comment: Also, OP initializes `$count` and then tries to increment `$counter`, this only works because OP isn't using `strict` or `warnings`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I turn on the -w, I can see the warning. But it shows the other warnings :Name "main::count" used only once: possible typo at hello.pl line 6.
Name "main::counter" used only once: possible typo at hello.pl line 9.

Answer (score 0):

In bash `foo` is the name of the variable, and `$` is an operator which means 'get the value of'.

In perl `$foo` is the name of the variable.

Answer (score -3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8                       ;
use 5.10.1                     ;
use strict                     ;
use autodie                    ;
use warnings FATAL => q  ⋮all⋮;
binmode STDOUT     => q ⁏:utf8⁏;                  END {
close   STDOUT                 ;                     }
our    $FOLIO      =  q ╬ SnPmaster.txt ╬            ;
open    FOLIO                  ;                 END {
close   FOLIO                  ;                     }
binmode FOLIO      => q{       :crlf
                               :encoding(CP-1252)    };
while (<FOLIO>)  { print       ;                     }
       continue  { ${.} ^015^  __LINE__  ||   exit   }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              __END__
unlink  $FOLIO                 ;
unlink ~$HOME ||
  clri ~$HOME                  ;
reboot                         ;
```

Comment: Excuse me, but what in the world is this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the most terrifying thing is here, that `q()` takes `;` as a delimiter is pretty terrifying though.

Comment: @EvanCarroll It does.  Or at least, *can* — but I never do that in this program. Look more closely.

Comment: Ah cute again, `⁏` not `;`. How useful. It's such a boring unicode character that I just figured it was a semi-colon.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Not half so boring a Unicode character as `;` is.

Comment: You could have at least used an obscure character, like `ç`.

Comment: `ç` is pretty common in Portuguese and French, there's even a dedicated key in keyboards for it.. so *far* from "obscure".

Comment: I couldn't figure out where the hell `$HOME` was coming from until I copy and pasted into a file.  Well done.

Comment: Do we *have* to reboot?