# Perl Script to Read File Line By Line and Run Command on Each Line

Tags: perl, bash, icu

I found this perl script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505381/perl-read-line-by-line) which seems will work for my purposes.  It opens a Unicode text file and reads each line so that a command can be run.  But I cannot figure out how to run a certain ICU command on each line.  Can someone help me out?  The error I get is (largefile is the script name): 
syntax error at ./largefile line 11, near "/ ."
Search pattern not terminated at ./largefile line 11.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'test.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {      
do
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=icu/source/lib/ ./a.out "$line" >> newtext.txt
done
}

close $info;
```

Basically I want to open a large text file and run the command (which normally runs from the command line...I think how I call this in the perl script is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it) "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=icu/source/lib/ ./a.out "$line" >> newtext.txt" on each line so that "newtext.txt" is then populated with all the lines after they have been processed by the script.  The ICU part is breaking words for Khmer.

Any help would be much appreciated!  I'm not much of a programmer...  Thanks!

Comment: is this command supposed to be run from command prompt or terminal?

Comment: I normally run LD_LIBRARY_PATH=icu/source/lib/ ./a.out "something here" >> newtext.txt inside the terminal in Ubuntu

Comment: aha, then put the whole command in system, like system("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=icu/source/lib/ ./a.out $line >> newtext.txt"); PS: semicolon is important, and so are the quotes

Comment: Sweet - I used:
 #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'test.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {   
    #print $line;    
system("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=icu/source/lib/ ./a.out '$line' >> newtext.txt");
}

close $info;

And it worked great!

Comment: If you put an answer I can select it.  Thanks again!

Comment: ok, i am adding the answer, glad i could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For executing terminal commands, the command needs to be in system(), hence change to

```
system("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=icu/source/lib/ ./a.out $line >> newtext.txt");
```

Comment: Would backticks or qx// do the same?

Comment: backticks returns the output from the running command. If you don't need the output then use system(). It is also good to check the return value of sytem. Or use http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::System::Simple or "autodie" to fetch errors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried backticks:

```
while (my $line = <$info>) {
  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=icu/source/lib/ ./a.out "$line" >> newtext.txt`
  last if $. == 2;
}
```