# Concatenate multiple files listed in a text file using perl Script

Tags: perl, concatenation

I am new at scripting and I am trying to concatenate multiple files, whose paths are listed a text file and output a combined gzip file. 
for example list file -  File_list.txt contains these file paths

```
/data/path/file1.txt
data2/path2/file2.txt
....file3.txt
....file4.txt
```

So far my code is for all files listed in a local directory ( outputs only combined file not gzipped):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use File::Slurp;

my $directory = 'Users/xyz/Documents/';

opendir(dir, $directory) or die $!;
my @files = readdir(dir);
closedir dir;

my $outfilename = 'Combined.fastq'

my $outfilesrc = undef;

foreach (sort @files){ 
  $outfilesrc.= File::Slurp::slurp("$basedir/$_");
}

open(OUT, "> $basedir/$outfilename") or die ("Can't open for writing: 
  $basedir/$outfilename : $!");
print OUT $outfilesrc;
close OUT;

exit;
```

Can someone please share how to read the files using this list rather than one single directory? 
I know it's much easier in simple bash but i am trying to create a module for a pipeline so need this in Perl. 
Thanks!

Comment: Try to read the list into an array, `@files`. See [The correct way to read a data file into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963400/the-correct-way-to-read-a-data-file-into-an-array)

Comment: ***"I know it's much easier in simple bash"*** That's only true when "simple bash" is the only language you know well

Comment: @Borodin Actually you don't need to "know well" bash scripting: cat \`cat file_list\` >> new_file is simpler than that perl script

Comment: Well, unless you want to deal with edge cases properly, because that example will break on e.g. filenames with spaces.

Comment: yes the command line/bash was easy for quick tasks with limited number of files. Since now the files can be scattered all over directory and and from different sources I need to code it to avoid any possible error

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to do anything with a zip file. I can't even begin to guess (`Archive::Zip` is pretty good though).

For concatenating a bunch of files, you can make use of the `ARGV` or `<>` filehandle.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $combined, '>', 'combined.fastq') or die $!; 

select $combined; 
print while <>; 

close $combined;
```

Should do the trick - you open an output file, select it as the default place to print, and then print every line captured in `<>` - which is all the data in any files specified on the command line, or piped data.

So invoking this script as `merge.pl *.txt` will take all the text files (in the current directory) and merge them into the combined file.

As you've got an input list - that's as simple as:

```
open ( my $list_of_files, '<', 'file_list.txt' ) or die;
chomp ( @ARGV = <$list_of_files>);
close ( $list_of_files );
```

This will accomplish the same result overall.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes didn't know I would have to apply this  script on bunch of large set files and then zip them up in the end. Also, I might have to use this script on zip files too, so I am thinking of using zcat for that. Would it be the recommended way?

Comment: zcat is for gzipped files. You cannot use zcat on zipped files. `Archive::Zip` is not for gzipped files. Look at `IO::Compress::Gzip` and `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip` for gzip. Look for instance here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48690/whats-the-difference-between-gunzip-and-unzip

Comment: Sorry its my fault, I am using it for multiple gzipped files which would be in GBs and since these are huge files I need to keep the scape/time used in mind too.

Comment: Different question that. Worth asking separately - and explaining what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your replies - The script runs well now, being new at perl it sounded difficult one to me. Just posting my code below -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;
use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip $GzipError);


my @data = read_file('./File_list.txt');
my $out = "./test.txt";


foreach my $data_file (@data)

{
    chomp($data_file);
    system("cat $data_file >> $out");
}
my $outzip = "./test.gz";
gzip $out => $outzip;
```