# Parsing a text file with multiple columns

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I am attempting to extract each of the 11 columns in the following file:

http://bioinfo.mc.vanderbilt.edu/TSGene/Human_716_TSGs.txt

...into a list of scalars for a beginning level college bioinformatics project. My effort, please see below, is effective but not perfect since the amount of whitespace varies between columns (please see the top of the file for details).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open FH, '<', 'tsg.txt' or die $!;
my $data = do {local $/; <FH>};
close FH or die $!;

my($id, $sym, $alias, $xref, $chromo, $band, $name, $gene_t, $desc, $nuc_seq,
   $pro_seq) = $data =~ /(\S+)\s+
                         (\S+)\s+
                         (\S+)\s+
                         (\S+)\s+
                         (\S+)\s+
                         (\S+)\s+

                         (\S+)\s+
                         /xms;

print "GeneID: $id", "\n";
print "Gene_symbol: $sym", "\n";
print "Alias: $alias", "\n";
print "XRef: $xref", "\n";
print "Chromosome: $chromo", "\n";
print "Cytoband: $band", "\n";

print "Full_name: $name", "\n";
#print "Gene_type: $gene_t", "\n";
#print "Description: $desc", "\n";
#print "Nucleotide_sequence: $nuc_seq", "\n";
#print "Protein_sequence: $pro_seq", "\n";
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file looks like its `tab` separated, you should be able to store each line into an array using `split` on `\t`:

```
my @columns = split( "\t", $data );
```

And then you can access your columns by indexing in:

```
my $id = $columns[0];
```

etc.

Comment: Hmm..quick question. When I parse the file, the next geneID is displayed at the bottom of the protein sequence. I have been struggling to determine why this is occurring since I am only accessing elements 0-10 (11 in total) tab separated fields.

Comment: Also, do you have any suggestions on how I could extract the same fields for the entire file? I am considering constructing a complex data structure, e.g.: $gene->{$name}{$cytoband} = $pro_seq;

Comment: @user1136670: There are plenty of answers on SO about reading files line by line in Perl.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505381/perl-read-line-by-line.