# Replacing a pattern in file without reading the whole file- Perl

Tags: perl

I want to replace a pattern 'good' with 'bad' in my file. Currently what I am doing is:

```
#!/perl/bin/perl

$filename= "abc.txt";

open my $fh, $filename;
my $text = do { local( $/ ); <$fh> };
close $fh;
$text =~s/good/bad/g;
```

Is there any way I can do this without reading the whole file??

Edit: Suppose I know that there's only 1 'good' in the file.

P.S.,Hi I am new here. Hope I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Of course not. How would you know how many `good` there are in a file without reading the whole file? :S

Comment: And suppose I know that there is only one 'good' in the file, then is there any way?

Comment: That's another question. You should point that in your OP. Yes you can. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505381/perl-read-line-by-line) on how to read a file line by line, this should be enough to solve your problem. Once you've hit a line that has `good` and replaced it, you can just exit the loop.

Comment: even for perl to know that the line does not have a good then it has to read that line.

Comment: @m0skit0 He is correct.. The flag 'g' replaces all occurrences of string 'good' with 'bad'

Comment: Okay thanks for replying. I have gone line by line, too. But I thought there was also some other way to do this. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I don't want to read the whole file, you don't want line by line... I don't know what you want ;D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Your code does not change the file; it changes the string containing the content read from the file. What are you going to do with the string after changing 'good' to 'bad'? If you are going to write it back to the original file, you are going to have to process the whole file. If you're going to write it to another file, you presumably need the whole file (though if you want to ignore everything after 'good', you could stop reading and writing early). If the files are small (up to a few hundred MiB), slurping the whole file is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Tie::File`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Tie::File;
my $filename = ...;
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $filename or die;
for (@lines) {
    s/good/bad/g and last;
}
```

Too make sure that not the whole file is slurped in you want to read the lines one-by-one, e.g. using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Tie::File;
my $filename = ...;
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $filename or die;
for(my $i=0; ; $i++) {
    last if !defined $lines[$i]; # eof
    last if $lines[$i] =~ s/good/bad/g;
}
```

Comment: But here too the whole file is being read into the '@lines' array, right?