# Reading my data six lines at a time does not work

Tags: perl

I have data for three locations, which I want to process. The data consists of a location name followed by 5 lines of data for each location. I have followed the post here: [Perl read line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505381/perl-read-line-by-line), but my mwe, below, only prints the file name instead. Off course, apart from printing I want to do other processing (e.g. writing some fields to another file), if only I can read the data correctly.

I will appreciate help

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
 use warnings;

my @locations=("Location1","Location2", "Location3");
my $locations;
my $file='locfile.txt';

open(my $INFILE, '<', $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";

for (my $ii=0; $ii < @locations; ++$ii){
my $locationname=scalar(<locfile.txt>);
for(1..5){
while(my $line=<locfile.txt>){
print "$line\n";
}
}
}
```

My data, which is read from a file, looks like below

```
Location1
30 24/33 RAIN IN THE MORNING, PARTLY CLOUDY AT NIGHT
31 24/33 SUNNY PERIODS. ISOLATED SHOWERS IN THE EVENING
01 24/33 SUNNY PERIODS. ISOLATED SHOWERS IN THE AFTERNOON
02 24/33 SUNNY PERIODS. ISOLATED SHOWERS IN THE AFTERNOON
03 24/33 PARTLY CLOUDY IN THE MORNING, RAIN THE AFTERNOON
Location2
30 24/33 RAIN IN THE MORNING, PARTLY CLOUDY AT NIGHT
31 24/33 SUNNY PERIODS. ISOLATED SHOWERS IN THE EVENING
01 24/33 SUNNY PERIODS. ISOLATED SHOWERS IN THE AFTERNOON
02 24/33 SUNNY PERIODS. ISOLATED SHOWERS IN THE AFTERNOON
03 24/33 PARTLY CLOUDY IN THE MORNING, RAIN THE AFTERNOON
Location3
30 24/33 RAIN IN THE MORNING, PARTLY CLOUDY AT NIGHT
31 24/33 SUNNY PERIODS. ISOLATED SHOWERS IN THE EVENING
01 24/33 SUNNY PERIODS. ISOLATED SHOWERS IN THE AFTERNOON
02 24/33 SUNNY PERIODS. ISOLATED SHOWERS IN THE AFTERNOON
03 24/33 PARTLY CLOUDY IN THE MORNING, RAIN THE AFTERNOON
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reading not just 5 lines, but until the end of the file 5 times!

```perl
for (my $index = 0; my $location = <$INFILE>; ++$index) {
   for (1..5) {
      defined( my $line = <$INFILE> )
         or warn("Premature EOF\n"), last;
     
      print "$location $index: $line";
   }
}
```

Note that I removed the need to know the number of location in advance. If you didn't want to rely on their being exactly five lines of data per location, you can use the following:

```perl
my $location;
my $index = -1;
while (<$INFILE>) {
   chomp;

   if (!/^\d/) {
      $location = $_;
      ++$index;
      next;
   }

   print "$location $index: $_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit weird, you open a file, but then you don't read from the returned file handle, but have the file name in pointy brackets again.

Your inner loop uses the `(1..5)` to get 5 lines, but inside that is a while loop that reads as much as it can, i.e., till EOF.

Here's the modified code. I've included `$ii` in the output to show which progression of the loop reads the lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @locations=("Location1","Location2", "Location3");
my $locations;

my $file='locfile.txt';
open(my $INFILE, '<', $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";

for (my $ii = 0; $ii < @locations; ++$ii) {
    my $locationname = scalar(<$INFILE>);
    for (1..5) {
        my $line = <$INFILE>;
        print "$locationname $ii: $line\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Robert. I did not realise I was trying from the file name instead of the handle, no wonder I was getting the file name printed. Your code works perfectly as I wanted. Once more thank you very much.

Comment: Re "*I was trying from the file name instead of the hand*", Oh, didn't notice that! haha

Comment: Sorry I meant I was reading the file and not reading from the file handle. I have tried the code from Robert and it works perfectly, which is why I upvoted it twice I do not see it up voted. The code from Ikegami is interesting. What does does if (!/^\d/) do?